# Backbone .fetch() adds one too many models

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I am using backbone's fetch method to retrieve a set of JSON from the server. Inside the fetch call, I have a success callback that correctly assigns attributes to a model for each object found.

`var foo = assetCollection.fetch({
    reset: true,
    success: function(response){
        var data = response.models[0].attributes.collection.items;
        data.forEach(function(data){
            assetCollection.add([
                {src_href: data.data[0].value,
                    title: data.data[1].value
                }
            ]);
        });
        console.log(assetCollection.models)
    }
})`

Right now I am working with a static set of JSON that has two objects. However, logging assetCollection.models returns three objects: the first is the initial server JSON response, while the next two are correctly parsed Backbone models.

How do I keep Backbone from adding the first object (the entire response from the server) to its set of models, and instead just add the two JSON objects that I am interested in?

The JSON object returned from the server is as follows:

`{
    "collection": {
        "version": "1.0",
        "items": [
            {
                "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/assets/d7070f64-9899-4eca-8ba8-4f35184e0853",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "name": "src_href",
                        "prompt": "Src_href",
                        "value": "http://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/36/590x/robin-williams-night-at-the-museum-498385.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "title",
                        "prompt": "Title",
                        "value": "Robin as Teddy Roosevelt"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/assets/d7070f64-9899-4eca-8ba8-4f35184e0853",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "name": "src_href",
                        "prompt": "Src_href",
                        "value": "http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/164/830/164830426_640.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "title",
                        "prompt": "Title",
                        "value": "Mrs. Doubtfire"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should modufy collection.

Probably you should change parse method:

```
yourCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    parse: function(data) {
        return data.models[0].attributes.collection.items;
    }
})
```

When you use fetch Backbone parse result and add all elements what you return in parse.